# jQuery - dynamic div height equal to the height of the whole window

Tags: jquery, css, html, resize, height

i am using the code found here [jQuery - dynamic div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443465/jquery-dynamic-div-height)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $('#center').css({'height':(($(window).height())-162)+'px'});

    $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#center').css({'height':(($(window).height())-162)+'px'});
    });
});
</script>
```

now the height change works fine when you resize the window, but if your scroll down the height does not change, this means the window property does not include things beyond the size of the browser window so if you scroll down the height does not increase

so what can i add that will be the size of the whole content not the window size

ANSWER
use document instead of window

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        $('#center').css({'height':(($(document).height())-162)+'px'});

        $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#center').css({'height':(($(document).height())-162)+'px'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
$(document).height()/width()
```

Is what you need? Since the window contains the document and the window has a fixed width and restricts what you're viewing from the document.

Comment: devided? ohh i see i should be using documents instead of window?

Comment: let me fix my code up and see if this works, but i think i just needed to use document instead of window THANKS

Comment: You should use `"body"` selector!

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
$("body").height();
```

Comment: thanks, i get the idea now, i just suck in programing so i really did not know what to change, thanks